# mysql select rows based on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

For example, the table structure is like this:

```
id   test_id
1      aaa
2      b
3      aaa
4      b
5      aaa
```

The question is I do not know the test_id is aaa. All I have is id = 3 and I want to get the result of row 1,3,5 because they all have the same test_id.   Could someone tell me how I can achieve this?  Thanks.

p.s: I do not know how to put the title for this question.  Or maybe is there any duplicates that I couldn't find? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select distinct t1.*
from table_name t1
inner join table_name t2 on t1.test_id=t2.test_id
where t2.id=3
```

Answer (score 1):

Using sql subquery:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE test_id IN (SELECT test_id FROM t1 WHERE id = '3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get this by using self join

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `table` t1
JOIN (SELECT test_id FROM `table` WHERE id = 3) t2
USING(test_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility with subquery

```
select id,test_id
from sometable
where test_id = 
(select test_id from sometable where id = 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use self join...
Im not sure about mysql..
this is SQLSERVER code (executable)..

```
     select distinct t1.id,t2.test_id 
     from table_id t1
     inner join
     table_id t2
     on
     t1.test_id = t2.test_id
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use Subquery**

> select * from table_name where test_id IN (SELECT test_id FROM table_name WHERE id = '3');